# How best to copy just parts of a tar file

Tags: backup, tar

I'm retired but I used to teach at a university.  I was supposed to destroy all records of student grades (it's a law), but I just noticed a bunch of my backups have years of my home directory from school.  This includes student problem solutions and grades. The ones still unpacked are easy because the directory structure allows me to just ditch the solutions and grades.

The tar files are a bit harder, and I wonder if there's a way to make it easy -- just copying to anther tar file minus some things I could specify with grep.  I'd like to keep some of my research work, so I don't want to just ditch the whole thing.

Fortunately, all this stuff is on disk, not tape, but I have a LOT of disks, and it just now took me most of a day just to mount each one and list all file names with ls -lR.  So anything to reduce the work would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to selectively "copy just parts of a tar file" that doesn't involve extracting the archive to a temporary location, deleting unwanted files, then creating a new archive.

However you may be able to copy the *whole* archive, then selectively delete files from that based on a filtered list of the archive's contents. For example, given a tar archive with the following files:

```
$ tar --list -f foo.tar
a/
a/c/
a/c/delete me
a/c/keep me
a/d/
a/d/keep me
a/e/
a/e/delete me
a/e/keep me
b/
b/c/
b/c/delete me
b/c/keep me
b/d/
b/d/keep me
b/e/
b/e/delete me
b/e/keep me
```

then

```
$ cp foo.tar foo.copy.tar
```

now test a filter:

```
$ tar --list -f foo.copy.tar --wildcards '*delete*'
a/c/delete me
a/e/delete me
b/c/delete me
b/e/delete me
```

(you could pipe the output of `tar --list` through a `grep` filter for more complicated patterns). If it looks OK, then

```
$ tar --list -f foo.copy.tar --wildcards '*delete*' |
    tar --delete -f foo.copy.tar --verbatim-files-from --files-from=-
```

Check the result

```
$ tar --list -f foo.copy.tar
a/
a/c/
a/c/keep me
a/d/
a/d/keep me
a/e/
a/e/keep me
b/
b/c/
b/c/keep me
b/d/
b/d/keep me
b/e/
b/e/keep me
```

Of course you could do the same thing on the original `foo.tar` if you prefer (there's just no chance of a do-over if the deletion goes wrong).

Note that it will fail for filenames containing newlines; although `--files-from` may be made to read a null-delimited list, as far as I know, `--list` can't be made to emit one. As well, `--delete` likely only works on *uncompressed* archives - if yours are compressed (`foo.tar.gz`, `foo.tar.xz` etc.) then you will need to uncompress first.

Comment: This is what I thoguht, but given the effort it is going to take, it was worth asking.  Thanks for the thorough answer.